# Why is there no select in the first apply-templates

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to understand `apply-templates` but I do not understand why I don't write any select="nodename" in the `apply-templates` here: (I think of the first apply-templates beneath the My CD collection)

**Snippet from the input document:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
  <p>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">
  Artist: <span style="color:#00ff00">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Taken from the w3schools tutorial. How does it understand which of the templates it should choose?

Comment: Can you edit your answer by adding the input document?

Comment: **TL;DR:** "`apply-templates` is an internal recursive process applied to all nodes of the tree (unless explicitly driven)."

Comment: English version: `apply-templates` is basically saying, "Put/Apply the rest of the content that goes under the enclosing `xsl:template`'s XML node `match`; iterate through its XML children, and apply the XSL for all of it right here."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As by the specs:

> In the absence of a select attribute, the xsl:apply-templates instruction processes all of the children of the current node, including text nodes.

`apply-templates` without XPath selection, applies the templates following the hierarchy of the XML tree view built by the processor during compilation, unless you explicitly drives the templates (as you did for `title` and `artist`).

You might also want to think of how [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) work. These rules run behind the scenes and allows recursive process go on in absence of a successful pattern match.

So if you omit the template match for the root `/` your templates will get executed anyway, thanks to the built-in rules.

I think the processing order should be like this:

- The template matches the root, and `xsl:apply-templates` tells the processor to apply the templates to the `catalog` element (in the place where it is invoked).
- No matching templates are found for `catalog`, so that the built-in rule allows continue processing toward the other descendant elements (`catalog`) until a new template with succesfull pattern match is found (`cd`)

The built-in rule runs behind the scenes and you must think always your transform as composed by your templates, plus a few additional hidden (but working) templates:

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()|@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()|comment()"/>
```

In your specific case the former template among the three above was the one resonsible for applying templates to the `cd` elements.

These built-in templates gets overridden each time you write an explicit template.

---

**Examples**

You can obtain the same by replacing:

```
<xsl:template match="cd">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

with:

```
<xsl:template match="country|company|price|year"/>

<xsl:template match="cd">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

---

About the root, in your case, you could also obtain the same by replacing:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

with

```
<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

or still:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

or still:

```
<xsl:template match="catalog">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @empo: Thank you, but is '/' equal to catalog, and not document root? I thought I had to write '/catalog' if I wanted the element root but is this part different from "normal" xpath? I may confuse things with each other...

Comment: @Andreas: no, `/` is the document root and not the `catalog`. In your case doe not make much difference. See my answer.

Comment: @empo: I am sorry but I do not yet understand it completely. I write a template that match '/' first right? That is the document root. Then I write apply-templates without a select which processes all of the children nodes of the current one, '/' right? I don't see how it can do the cd's.

Comment: @Andreas: A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Still, the XML tree view  hierarchy is followed by default. read carefully my answer.

Comment: @Andreas: "I don't see how it can do the cd's." That happens because `apply-templates` is an internal recursive process applied to all nodes of the tree (unless explicitly driven).

Comment: @empo: so it does not stop by the first child? Which is catalog? It continue to cd?

Comment: I found out that there are some built in rules that I was not aware of.

Comment: @Andreas: you might need to read something about built-in rules (spec references added to my answer now). These rules allows the process continue to `cd` even if no explicit `apply-templates` is provided.

Comment: @empo: thank you for your help. So to recap just to check if I have understood it correctly it works like this: the template match '/' then it tries to match catalog, but it does not have a explicit template so it uses its built in and apply templates to it children which finds CDs, correct?

Comment: @Andreas: yes, if you write an explicit template you actually are overriding the built-in rule. See my answer, now corrected to explain the order in which the tree is parsed.